# parse.com export database table into *.csv stored in parse cloud

Tags: csv, parse-platform, export

How can I export the one database table from parse.com into a *.csv file which is stored in parse online?
I just once got a file in the following format and now I need to do that on my own:

http://files.parsetfss.com/f0e70754-45fe-43c2-5555-6a8a0795454f/tfss-63214f6e-1f09-481c-83a2-21a70d52091f-STUDENT.csv

So, the question is how can I do this? I have not found a dashboard function yet

Thank you very much

Comment: That link looks like an uploaded file, not a table export. You need to convert the JSON export to CSV yourself.

Comment: Thx. Luckily I have these data in parse.com database.
Do you know how I could create a csv export for this particular table out of parse such that the generated csv file is stored in `http://files.parsetfss.com/....`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job in cloud code which will query through all the rows in the table and generate CSV data for each. This data can then be saved to a parse file for access by URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to simply export a class every once in awhile and you are on a mac, check out ParseToCSV on the Mac App Store. Works very well.